# How to delete old versions automatically from google-cloud-storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am writing files html files to GCS on every update to site related data. The website maintains versions so that manual revert is an option. I need to delete files of previous (not last) versions that are older than 2 days. 
Is there a way in GCS configurations where I can set expiry on previous versions while creating the next version?
or a scheduled delete based creation date of next version?

If not, what is the best way to do it from app-engine cron?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable [object versioning](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) in your bucket, and then use Lifecycle configuration to set up the rules for old versions. For example, to delete versions that have not been current for more than 30 days:

```
echo '
{
  "rule":
  [
    {
      "action": {"type": "Delete"},
      "condition": {
        "daysSinceNoncurrentTime": 30
      }
    }
  ]
}
' > /tmp/lifecycle.json
gsutil lifecycle set /tmp/lifecycle.json gs://yourbucket
```

Alternatively, you can remember keys for old versions in the Datastore. You can periodically query for these objects, and use GSC keys or file names to delete the old files.

Comment: thanks, 'Object Lifecycle Management' sounds like will serve my purpose by setting TTL on previous version while adding new. Will try this and post here.